StreamBuilder: filter stream data and display new results (gets stuck on ConnectionState.waiting)
I am loading data from Firebase and displaying it, this works perfectly fine. Now I want to let the user filter the results on the client-side. This is what doesn't work.
I am using a StreamController and use the add method to send new user events. Somehow this works fine when getting data from Firebase, but not when I try to switch to the filtered results manually.
Context
Here is the normal code for the initial loading from Firebase:
class UserViewModel {
final UserRepository _userRepo;
      
final StreamController<List<AppUser>> _allUsersStreamcontroller =
      StreamController<List<AppUser>>.broadcast();
List<AppUser> allUsersList = List.empty(growable: true);

// ... other code ...

  Stream<List<AppUser>> getUserStream() {
    return _allUsersStreamcontroller.stream;
  }

Future<bool> loadAllUsersInRadius() async {
    try {
      await _userRepo.getCurrentUserLocation();
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e);
    }

    // Basically load users & auto-filter some results
    if (_userRepo.currentLocation != null) {
      final subcription = _userRepo
          .getAllUsersInRadius(radius: searchRadius)
          .listen((documentList) {
        final filteredUserList =
            _applyAutomaticFilters(documentList, userRelationIDs);

        allUsersList = filteredUserList
            .map((docSnapshot) => _createUserFromSnapshot(docSnapshot))
            .toList();

          _allUsersStreamcontroller.add(allUsersList); // <- Important part, adding users to stream (this works)

      });
      subscriptions.add(subcription);
    }
    return true;
  }

  // ... Other code ...

And StreamBuilder in the UI:
 StreamBuilder<List<AppUser>>(
  // Added random key because otherwise Widget didn't update reliably (suggestion from another SO question)
  key: Key(Random().nextInt(10).toString()),
  stream: userViewModel.getUserStream(), // <- getting stream data
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (_swiperEnded || (snapshot.data?.isEmpty ?? false)) {
        // ... display some hint for user about empty list ...
      } else {
        // ... display main UI content ... <- Works fine normally
      }
    } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); // <- This is where it gets stuck after I apply manual filters
    } else if (snapshot.hasError || _errorMessage != null) {
      // Display error
    } else {
      // Unimportant
    }
  })

// ... other Widgets ...
// This is where the manual filters are applied, from a BottomSheet
ElevatedButton(
  child: const Text("Apply"),
  onPressed: () {
    userVM.applyManualFilters();
    setState(() {});                                              
    Navigator.pop(sheetContext, true);
  })

Now here is the part where it doesn't work. I take the user list and filter the contents based on the filter values. Then I try to add this new list to the same StreamController.
  void applyManualFilters() {
    Iterable<AppUser> filteredUserList = List.from(allUsersList);

    if (isTimeZoneFilterActive)
      filteredUserList = _filterByTimeZoneOffset(filteredUserList);
    if (isAvailabilityFilterActive)
      filteredUserList = _filterByAvailability(filteredUserList);
    if (isAgeFilterActive)
      filteredUserList = _filterByAgeRange(filteredUserList);

    _allUsersStreamcontroller.add(filteredUserList.toList()); // <- setting filtered data here, does NOT work
  }

My Problem
For some reason when I add the filteredUserList to the stream, it gets stuck on ConnectionState.waiting and the emulator starts eating resources like crazy (laptop starts getting very loud). It seems to get stuck in an infinite loop?
What I've tried: I tried using two different streams instead and then switching between them in the StreamBuilder based on a bool flag, but that ended the same.

I saw many other questions related to switching streams or similar ideas (1, 2, 3) but all the answers there sit at 0 points or don't help at all.
I've seen one suggestion in this SO question to use BehaviorSubject from RxDart which seems like it'd work, but I'd really prefer not to import a whole state management package just for this one instance.

The issue is the random key, because the broadcasting streams don't buffer, the events that you add are going to be sent to the old StreamBuilder. Adding a delay to the add doesn't really solve the problem, it just works because the rebuild takes less that 100ms.
I imagine that the reason that you added that random key is because the StreamBuilder wouldn't reflect changes when calling setState, this is because you reused the StreamController stream, StreamBuilder compares the streams in it's didUpdateWidget and if you pass the same reference it wont update.
final controller = StreamController();
final stream = controller.stream;
print(controller.stream == stream); // true

In this example you can see the cause a bit more clearly, comment one or both of the lines marked to fix the StreamBuilder's behavior.
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const App());

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  AppState createState() => AppState();
}

typedef User = String;
typedef Users = List<User>;

class AppState extends State<App> {
  final controller = StreamController<Users>.broadcast()..stream.listen(print);

  Widget _stream_builder(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Users> snapshot) {
    return switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      ConnectionState.none => const Text('None'),
      ConnectionState.waiting => const Text('Waiting'),
      ConnectionState.done => Text('Done -> ${snapshot.data}'),
      ConnectionState.active => Text('Active -> ${snapshot.data}'),
    };
  }

  int _number = 0;
  Key get _rand_key => ValueKey(Random().nextDouble());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
          key: _rand_key, // <- Comment out this or the setState
          stream: controller.stream,
          builder: _stream_builder,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (!controller.isClosed) {
              controller.add(['$_number']);
              if (++_number > 5) {
                controller.close();
              }
            }
            setState(() {}); // <- Comment out this or the key
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I don't think that using broadcast stream is necessary in your case, only one widget needs to receive the stream, the rest can do just fine with a reference or a InheritedModel. This example is a bit more in line with how I would do the filtering.
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const App());

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  AppState createState() => AppState();
}

typedef User = String;
typedef Users = List<User>;

class AppState extends State<App> {
  UsersFilter filter = UsersFilter(invalid_users: ['0', '2', '3', '5', '9']);

  // This is more efficient if you are mainly reading and modifying, keep in
  // mind that you are free to modify the contents of the list, this only
  // restricts the resizing of the list. If you want a bit more flexibility,
  // check the [ChangeNotifier]'s implementation.
  Users users = _empty_list;
  static final _empty_list = Users.empty();

  // This is a getter just to reflect that it should be treated as a
  // variable, like if it was created by the [StreamController]
  Stream<Users> get _users_stream async* {
    users = _empty_list; // Same as `users.clear()`

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      await Future.delayed(Durations.extralong1);
      yield ['$i', '${i * 2}'];
    }
  }

  Widget _stream_builder(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Users> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData)
      users = users.followedBy(snapshot.data!).toList(growable: false);

    return switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      ConnectionState.none => const Text('None'),
      ConnectionState.waiting => const Text('Waiting'),
      ConnectionState.done => Text('Done -> ${snapshot.data} \n $users'),
      ConnectionState.active => Text('Active -> ${snapshot.data} \n $users'),
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _users_stream.transform(filter),
          builder: _stream_builder,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => setState(() {}), // reset
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UsersFilter extends StreamTransformerBase<Users, Users> {
  final Users invalid_users;
  UsersFilter({required this.invalid_users});

  @override
  Stream<Users> bind(Stream<Users> stream) async* {
    await for (final users in stream) {
      yield users..removeWhere((user) => invalid_users.contains(user));
    }
  }
}


How interesting, you're right. Without the random key I don't need the time delay anymore. (But now it also looks kind of static now, before it'd show the loading indicator every time I changed the radius or filters, which is better user feedback. Maybe I'll find a way to manually set the waiting state for a few milliseconds.)

Anyway, I also tried using the transform() and map() functions to be closer to how streams are supposed to be handled I suppose, but it just feels like it just makes things unintuitive (and maybe I'm just too inexperienced with this stuff). So I I'll stick with my approach so far, but you've helped me understand things much better, thank you.

If you have animations, handle them in the _users_stream function, calls you do in that function body are in order, meaning that you can step the animations with each yield. map() is not that necessary if you handle the request only in the _users_stream as you can just  yield users; return;  to apply a new filter, this would work better if you keep the entire request in cache.

I'm not sure where exactly your problem is, but I'd say it is in loadAllUsersInRadius where you create a new subscription every time it is called.
You are referring to questions about switching streams, that is not what you need. You need to combine streams. I'll give an example below. Note that the kind of stream is not really important. They are all just streams that behave slightly differently. I'll be using rxdart. It contains some really powerful operations on streams.
  Stream<List<User>> $allUsers = userRepo.getAllUsers();
  Stream<FilterData> $filterData = ...someSteam; //Could be a stream controller, a BehaviorSubject or a ReplaySubject

  Stream<List<User>> $filteredUsers = Rx.combineLatest2($allUsers, $filterData, (a,b) => [a,b])
    .map((data) => { // Transform data from both streams to a new stream
      List<User> users = data[0] as List<User>;
      FilterData filterData = data[1] as filterData;

      return users.where((x) => x.prop1 == filterData.prop1 && x.prop2 == filterData.prop2); //Return filtered users to stream

    });


CombineLatest does as the name suggests, combine 2 streams and emits them as a signal value. The Stream will not emit until all Streams have emitted at least one item. When either $allUsers or $filterData change CombineLatest emits a new value and so does the $fitleredUsers;

Thank you for your contribution. It wasn't really a direct solution to my problem, but it made me re-check my whole stream and controller structure. This way I was able to find my basic error (and I fixed the multiple subscriber thing as well).

Your suggestion also made me look deeper into RxDart, and even though my app is simple enough to work without it for now, I might consider using it after all in the future.

After a LOT of testing, I had to find that the problem was a very basic one. The adding of new data to the stream + setState of my UI happened nearly at the same time, so the StreamBuilder never caught the stream data because it was sent right before it updated.
Giving the data event a time buffer fixed everything:
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        () => _allUsersStreamcontroller.add(filteredUserList.toList()));

